# g++ with python.h, how to compile

Tags: c++, python, makefile

I compile one test code with g++ without any issue.

```cpp
#include "Python.h"  

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{  
    Py_Initialize();  
    PyRun_SimpleString("import pylab");  
    PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.plot(range(5))");  
    PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.show()");  
    Py_Exit(0);  
}
```

`g++ -o test test.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7`
works fine and runs.

But when I try to embed this code into another project, it fails. It really confuses me.

Makefile is like the following.

```
CXX=g++  
CXXFLAGS=-DIB_USE_STD_STRING -Wall -Wno-switch -g  
ROOT_DIR=..  
BASE_SRC_DIR=${ROOT_DIR}/PosixSocketClient  
INCLUDES=-I${ROOT_DIR}/Shared/ -I${BASE_SRC_DIR} -I/usr/include/python2.7  
LIBRARY=-L/usr/lib/python2.7/config  
TARGET=eu  

$(TARGET):  
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o EClientSocketBase.o -c   $(BASE_SRC_DIR)/EClientSocketBase.cpp  
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o EPosixClientSocket.o -c   $(BASE_SRC_DIR)/EPosixClientSocket.cpp  
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o PosixTestClient.o -c PosixTestClient.cpp  
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o Main.o -c Main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(LIBRARY) -lpython2.7 -o $@ EClientSocketBase.o EPosixClientSocket.o PosixTestClient.o Main.o 

clean:  
    rm -f $(TARGET) *.o
```

This project compiles fine and runs, the only change I made was adding the test code in the Main.cpp file. warning/error message shows:

> In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
>                    from Main.cpp:15:
>   /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1158:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
>   /usr/include/features.h:163:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
>   /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1180:0: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
>   /usr/include/features.h:165:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
>   g++ -L/usr/lib/ -lpython2.7 -ldl -lutil -o eu EClientSocketBase.o EPosixClientSocket.o PosixTestClient.o Main.o
>   Main.o: In function `main':
>
>   /home/bbc/TWS/IBJts/cpp/eu-ats/Main.cpp:81: undefined reference to`Py_Initialize'
>   /home/bbc/TWS/IBJts/cpp/eu-ats/Main.cpp:82: undefined reference to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
>
>   /home/bbc/TWS/IBJts/cpp/eu-ats/Main.cpp:83: undefined reference to`PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
>   /home/bbc/TWS/IBJts/cpp/eu-ats/Main.cpp:84: undefined reference to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
>
>   /home/bbc/TWS/IBJts/cpp/eu-ats/Main.cpp:85: undefined reference to`Py_Exit'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [eu] Error 1

any help? thank you!

Comment: maybe lib python is a "normal" C library, so you likely have to include it using `external "C" { .. }` to assure C "linkage" (indeed surely the .h does it itself checking if it is running under C or C++ compiler...)

Comment: Try nm libpython2.7.so | grep Py_Initialize and see if this symbol is in the library.

Comment: You added a few lines to `main.cpp` and got several errors. Try reverting to the old version, verifying that it works, then adding just the `#include "Python.h"` line and see what happens. I'll bet you get the "redefined" errors but not the "undefined" errors, which means you probably just forgot to put a header guard in a header file somewhere. Once that works, we can tackle the "undefined" errors, which probably come from failing to link an object file (like `Python.o`).

Comment: solved it, the real problem in makefile is the order of parameters, I didn't know the order matters(order in one line).

Comment: To get rid of the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` warning, make sure to include `Python.h` first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at Lucas's comment for the answer:

"To get rid of the _POSIX_C_SOURCE warning, make sure to include Python.h before all other header files."

I had the same problem.  I use Boost Python, so for me I moved the include of boost/python.hpp to the first line in my .cpp file.

(Lukas, post your comment as an answer so the person who asked can mark it as the right answer, and the question won't remain 'unanswered' in StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Python: https://bugs.python.org/issue1045893

If you include first Python.h, the compiler won't complain but GNU libc's /usr/include/features.h will override it anyway when _GNU_SOURCE is defined:

# undef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
 # define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
 # undef _XOPEN_SOURCE
 # define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700