# Embedding matplotlib in C++

Tags: c++, python, matplotlib

I am reading a message from a socket with C++ code and am trying to plot it interactively with `matplotlib`, but it seems Python code will block the main thread, no matter I use `show()` or `ion()` and `draw()`. `ion()` and `draw()` won't block in Python.

Any idea how to plot interactively with `matplotlib` in C++ code?

An example would be really good.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you doing so far that doesn't work? How do you get the data into python? It's not really clear what you're actually trying to do. For example, are you trying to source data from c++ code and plot it using IPython?

Comment: Ah, I presume this has something to do with your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10056393/709852)?

Comment: hi, I figured the answer to my other question out. this question is regarding using matplotlib in c++, c++ code read data, and matplotlib is called to plot the data received interactively. I call something like 
PyRun_SimpleString("import pylab");  PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.ion()");  PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.plot(range(5))"); PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.draw()");  

it blocks the main c++ thread even with draw(), not show()

Comment: So those calls are made inside a new thread? It sounds like you're interacting unfavourable with the [global interpreter lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Unfortunately, I don't know anything about how The Very High Level Layer interacts with the GIL. I suspect it grabs it and gives it back when the call returns. Does it return? If you're just using python to plot, why not pipe the data to a python process?

Comment: 1st, there is no separate thread for python code part.
it's just something sequential, 
c++ code, python plot, c++ code

the reason I don't want python to receive the data is, the official api from broker is in c++, I open a socket connection, and receive message in c++ code, then I want to plot it interactively with matplotlib as I am more familiar with charting functionality of it.

Comment: Ok, so as I understand it, you have some C++ library that you wish to use, but plot the data from within python? Can you not go the other way - calling the C++ library from within Python? That's a lot easier to do and is much more widely understood.

Comment: @HenryGomersall, The GIL only keeps code which wants to hold it from executing. Other code (code which does not touch Python objects) is not affected by that lock, but only by the locks that it actually needs to hold.

Comment: @MikeGraham I'm happy with that. Regarding the original question, one might imagine (though I've no idea, so its hypothetical) that a new thread is spawned to draw the plot, which grabs the GIL, then the main thread is not able to get it in order to return, possibly due to pylab doing something obnoxious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may also try creating a new thread that does the call to the
blocking function, so that it does not block IO in your main program
loop.  Use an array of thread objects and loop through to find an unused
one, create a thread to do the blocking calls, and have another thread
that joins them when they are completed.

This code is a quick slap-together I did to demonstrate what I mean about
using threads to get pseudo asynchronous behavior for blocking functions...
I have not compiled it or combed over it very well, it is simply to show
you how to accomplish this.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string>
#include <memory.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define MAX_THREADS 256 // Make this as low as possible!
using namespace std;
pthread_t PTHREAD_NULL;
typedef string someTypeOrStruct;
class MyClass
{
    typedef struct
    {
        int id;
        MyClass *obj;
        someTypeOrStruct input;
    } thread_data;

    void draw();    //Undefined in this example
    bool getInput(someTypeOrStruct *);  //Undefined in this example
    int AsyncDraw(MyClass * obj, someTypeOrStruct &input);
    static void * Joiner(MyClass * obj);
    static void * DoDraw(thread_data *arg);
    pthread_t thread[MAX_THREADS], JoinThread;
    bool threadRunning[MAX_THREADS], StopJoinThread;

    bool exitRequested;
public:
    void Main();
};

bool MyClass::getInput(someTypeOrStruct *input)
{
}

void MyClass::Main()
{
    exitRequested = false;
    pthread_create( &JoinThread, NULL, (void *(*)(void *))MyClass::Joiner, this);

    while(!exitRequested)
    {
        someTypeOrStruct tmpinput;
        if(getInput(&tmpinput))
            AsyncDraw(this, tmpinput);
    }

    if(JoinThread != PTHREAD_NULL)
    {
        StopJoinThread = true;
        pthread_join(JoinThread, NULL);
    }
}

void *MyClass::DoDraw(thread_data *arg)
{
    if(arg == NULL) return NULL;
    thread_data *data = (thread_data *) arg;
    data->obj->threadRunning[data->id] = true;
    // -> Do your draw here <- //
    free(arg);
    data->obj->threadRunning[data->id] = false; // Let the joinThread know we are done with this handle...
}

int MyClass::AsyncDraw(MyClass *obj, someTypeOrStruct &input)
{
    int timeout = 10; // Adjust higher to make it try harder...
    while(timeout)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
        {
            if(thread[i] == PTHREAD_NULL)
            {
                thread_data *data = (thread_data *)malloc(sizeof(thread_data));
                if(data)
                {
                    data->id = i;
                    data->obj = this;
                    data->input = input;

                    pthread_create( &(thread[i]), NULL,(void* (*)(void*))MyClass::DoDraw, (void *)&data);
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
        timeout--;
    }
}

void *MyClass::Joiner(MyClass * obj)
{
    obj->StopJoinThread = false;
    while(!obj->StopJoinThread)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
            if(!obj->threadRunning[i] && obj->thread[i] != PTHREAD_NULL)
            {
                pthread_join(obj->thread[i], NULL);
                obj->thread[i] = PTHREAD_NULL;
            }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyClass base;
    base.Main();
    return 0;
}
```

This way you can continue accepting input while the draw is occurring.

~~Fixed so the above code actually compiles, make sure to add -lpthread